# Symfony Assert doesnt working with form

Tags: php, symfony, validation, assert

I used Assert to validate fields like

```
@Assert\NotBlank(message="this field cannot be empty")
$private title;

@Assert\NotBlank(message="this field cannot be empty")
$private description;

@Assert\NotBlank(message="this field cannot be empty")
$private price;
```

Now, when Im using form in html.twig

```
{% body block %}
{{ form(form, {"attr": {"novalidate": "novalidate"}}) }}
{% endblock %}
```

everything is allright, if I have an empty field I got my message, but when Im trying to divide this form like

```
{% body block %}

{{ form_start(form, {"attr": {"novalidate": "novalidate"}}) }}
{{ form_widget(form.title) }}
{{ form_widget(form.description) }}
{{ form_widget(form.price) }}
{{ form_rest(form) }}
{{ form_end(form, {"attr": {"novalidate": "novalidate"}}) }}

{% endblock %}
```

I'm getting something like default message that I cannot add an advert, but there are no messages next to my fields. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried use novalidate attribute in every form field but it still doesn't working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `{{ form_row(form.title) }}` instead `{{ form_widget(form.title) }}` and so on. Alternatively add `{{ form_error(form.title) }}` to every `{{ form_widget(form.title) }}` and so on.

**Explanation:** `form_widget` render only form control ie. input box or drop-down. `form_row` render: `form_label` - the title of field, `form_widget` - the control, `form_error` if needed - the errors attached to field. It also wrap everything on nice `div` to group related parts.

Comment: Ok, I'll be at home for few hours and I will check this solution, thanks :)